# Disk usage analyser does not display correct disk size (using multiple mount points)

Tags: 13.04, acer, disk-usage, aspire, mountpoint

I'm running ubuntu 13.04 on an acer aspire S3, and everything is going pretty smoothly. However, one thing that I did notice was an error in disk usage analyser

I have the Caching SSD that was used by windows 8 now mounted at /, with the 500 GB hard drive mounted as /home, to store all the large files. However, it lists the file system as 20GB

Is this intentional? It makes judging hard drive usage difficult. Any enlightenment would be appreciated

Thanks,
Jack

*PS. As you can probably tell by the fact that this is the most urgent problem I have, the experience with ubuntu on this laptop has been pretty flawless so far!*

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, but if it says it's a 20 GB volume, then that's what it is ( you must have installed in a 20 GB partition ).

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question?

Comment: @psusi I have / mounted to a 20GB SSD and /home on a 500GB hard drive, but there is no 500GB volume listed. It just seemed odd to me

Comment: @Mitch Output is too long to post here, but is this the issue? WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Comment: Post the output in your question via pastebin.ubuntu.com!

Comment: What does `df` show?  The disk usage analyser should show both drives if you have them mounted that way.